Unclear behaviour of std::next_permutation with std::wstring
Given this program to play around with Unicode, I found results that don't make sense to me:
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
    std::wcout.imbue(std::locale());
    std::wstring unicodeString = L"⊓⊔⊏";           // FAIL!

// 6 permutations as expected
//  std::wstring unicodeString = L"abc";           // OK

    size_t permutations_count = 0;
    // Print the Unicode string
    do {
        std::wcout << unicodeString << std::endl;
        permutations_count++;
    } while (std::next_permutation(unicodeString.begin(),unicodeString.end()));

    std::wcout << "sizeof char " << sizeof(char) << std::endl;
    std::wcout << "sizeof wchar_t " << sizeof(wchar_t) << std::endl;
    std::wcout << "string size: " << unicodeString.size() << std::endl;
    std::wcout << "permutations: " << permutations_count << std::endl;
    assert(permutations_count == 6);

    return 0;
}

GCC 11.4.0 and Clang 19.0.0git return (g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra, clang++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra):
⊓⊔⊏
⊔⊏⊓
⊔⊓⊏
sizeof char 1
sizeof wchar_t 4
string size: 3
permutations: 3
a.out: /mnt/c/Workspace/test.cc:26: int main(): Assertion `permutations_count == 6' failed.
Aborted

Which for some reason didn't print all 3! == 6 permutations of "⊓⊔⊏". It works correctly when the string "abc" is provided to next_permutation,  however, indicating a mishandling of the multi-byte values by my code somehow.
MSVC CL 19.40.33811 (cl /EHsc /std:c++17) also prints unclear results,
... thousands of lines cut ...
""SSâS?ââ
""SSâSâ?â
""SSâSââ?
""SSS?âââ
""SSSâ?ââ
""SSSââ?â
""SSSâââ?
sizeof char 1
sizeof wchar_t 2
string size: 9
permutations: 6,725
Assertion failed: permutations_count == 6, file test.cc, line 26

There's differences in what naively appears to be a standards-compliant and portable program between the vendors, and none of those behaviours make sense to me. Other notes,

My source file is encoded using UTF-8. I tried other ways of writing the unicodeString, like std::string unicodeString = u8"⊓⊔⊏";, but this also returns unexpected results.

I assume that wstring is designed to deal with "wide characters" (2 bytes with cl, 4 with g++/clang++) rather than bytes, as seems to be the interface used by the generic algorithms.


Please may someone explain what is being done incorrectly here?

Aside from the ordering problem and the source encoding issue: Not relevant to your particular example, but be aware that all standard library functionality, including next_permutation will act on individual code units, not code points or characters in any meaning. So if you try to for example permute , then you'll get two sequences on MSVC because  takes up two UTF-16 code units with the second sequence being invalid UTF-16. Similarly, if you have e.g. ä as sequence, depending on normalization, this may be one or two code points (and units) with a non-sensical permutation.

What is the system locale? OR in which locale you are expecting this behavior.

next_permutation only iterates through all permutations if the input was sorted, but ⊓⊔⊏ is not sorted.  This is why GCC 11.4.0 and Clang 19.0.0 are not emitting the results you expected.
MSVC CL 19.40.33811 is a more complex case. The only way I can think of that it ended up with 9 characters is that your cpp file is UTF-8, and thus the string is saved as the bytes 0xe2 0x8a 0x93 0xe2 0x8a 0x94 0xe2 0x8a 0x8f, but then the compiler interpreted the file as some other code page (probably CP-1252), so interpreted each byte as a separate character, and then stored these as separate wchar_t characters in a UTF-16 wstring. This is a common mistake, called Mojibake. A 9 character string would result in 362,880 permutations.... except that your input is not sorted.
Tangentially to this, when it writes the bytes to the terminal, the terminal is interpreting these bytes as some other encoding (probably CP-1252), and is thus displaying the wrong characters in the terminal.

Footnote: next_permutation is well defined for any input, and simply moves to the next input in sorted order. When the next input would be "less" than the current state, it returns false.  Ergo: if you want to easily iterate over all permutations, then you should start in a sorted state, and iterate until it returns false.  But next_permutation is not limited to this case, and it is well defined to use it in other interesting ways.

Thank you for explaining that, I learned a lot!

@user26340612 The algorithm functions are guaranteed to work if called correctly, and the preconditions are met (in this case, the data must be sorted).   All next_permutation sees is a collection of T and runs the algorithm.   The requirement for next_permutation to use data that is sorted is here.  Unsorted data leads to undefined behavior.  Look at items 1) and 2) at the link.

next_permutation only iterates through all permutations if the input was sorted - this is bad statement. You can start iteration from any permutation and function will return false when range will become stored after next_permutation.

@PaulMcKenzie It does not lead to undefined behavior. next_permutation will however stop (return false) when the last permutation in lexicographical order is reached.

@MarekR: Technically what I wrote was a correct oversimplification. You're right that I should have made that clearer in the answer, and have now added that as a footnote.

This code has multiple problems.

You are configuring locale incorrectly. For details see my other answer - note all 5 bullet points about encoding pitfalls. On other platforms/copilers everywhere UTF-8 is assumed, so this problem do not come up so often. To fix it add compilation flag /utf-8 and in code it should be:

int main() {
#if 0
    std::locale::global(std::locale{"en_US.UTF-8"}); // replace en_US with your language
#else
    // or use system language settings and enforce UTF-8:
    std::locale::global(std::locale{std::locale{""}, "en_US.UTF-8", std::locale::ctype});
#endif
    std::wcout.imbue(std::locale{""});

After that printing on MSVC will work (assuming your code page supports this characters).

The other problem is that characters in your initial string are not sorted, so iteration over all permutation are starting from the middle. Demo. (this is covered by other answer).

3. If you are expecting that locale will impact order of characters. Then see this, documentation of less operator: - my mistake operator< less for std::wstring is not in use.

The relevant comparison is done on the individual wchar_t, not using std::basic_string's operator<. That doesn't make a difference for std::wstring, because std::char_traits<wchar_t> member functions eq and lt are required to behave identical to the built-in == and < on wchar_t. However, if it was some other std::basic_string specialization, there could be a difference, because the corresponding char_trait can reorder characters or consider some to be equal.

Or a different way: Even with a non-default std::char_traits specialization std::next_permutation on the string will still not be local-sensitive, but order by value of code units instead.
